# rownum issue in oracle query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, rownum

I m trying to run this query but it returns zero rows. Any clues why?

```
Select distinct a.id
from  table1 a, table b
where  ( a.id= b.id or a.id = b.secondid ) and rownum < 200;
```

But if I run the above query without the ROWNUM clause it finds records:

```
Select distinct a.id
from  table1 a, table b
where  ( a.id= b.id or a.id = b.secondid );
```

I'm confused why the first query is not working.

Comment: . . saying "it is not working" is not helpful.  You should say what the problem is.

Comment: not working means not getting the correct output. It returned Zero rows if i add rownum in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the thread below. Pretty good explanations.
https://community.oracle.com/thread/210143
 Here are two working solutions.

1. Use the row_number function for 8i and 9i :
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  ASC) AS ROW_NUMBER.
2. Reuse Rownum pseudo column (This seems to be better)
   SELECT * 
   FROM ( 
   SELECT t.*, ROWNUM AS rn 
   FROM ( 
   SELECT * 
   FROM mytable 
   ORDER BY
   paginator, id 
   ) t 
   ) 
   WHERE rn BETWEEN 1 AND 3

Answer (score 4):

You need to apply `ROWNUM` *after* Oracle figures out which rows to return. The only reliable way is this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  Select distinct a.id
  from  table1 a, table b
  where  ( a.id= b.id or a.id = b.secondid )
) WHERE ROWNUM < 200;
```

Comment: yes thanks, i figured that out but i was thinking it should have worked before as well. like if you remove the or clause then it works.e.g.   Select distinct a.id
from  table1 a, table b
where  a.id= b.id  and rownum < 200;

Comment: @Neeraj - there are some cases where `ROWNUM` will work without resorting to an outer query, but they're rare. There's a pretty good explanation on the Oracle "Ask Tom" site [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:948366252775).

Answer (score -1):

Change "and rownum < 200" to "WHERE rownum < 200"