# Selecting top n Oracle records with ROWNUM still valid in subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have the following FireBird query:

```
update hrs h
set h.plan_week_id=
  (select first 1 c.plan_week_id from calendar c
   where c.calendar_id=h.calendar_id)
where coalesce(h.calendar_id,0) <> 0
```

(Intention: For records in `hrs` with a (non-zero) `calendar_id` 
            take `calendar.plan_week_id` and put it in `hrs.plan_week_id`)

The trick to select the first record in Oracle is to use [WHERE ROWNUM=1](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_select_the_top_n_rows_from_a_table), **and** if understand correctly [I do not have to use ROWNUM in a separate outer query because I 'only' match ROWNUM=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590215/rownum-issue-in-oracle-query) - thanks SO for suggesting *Questions that may already have your answer* ;-)

This would make it

```
update hrs h
set h.plan_week_id=
  (select c.plan_week_id from calendar c
   where (c.calendar_id=h.calendar_id) and (rownum=1))
where coalesce(h.calendar_id,0) <> 0
```

I'm actually using the 'first record' together with the selection of only **one** field to guarantee that I get **one value** back which can be put into `h.plan_week_id`.

Question: **Will the above query work under Oracle as intended?**

Right now, I do not have a filled Oracle DB at hand to run the query on.

Comment: [Here is sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4) where you could try the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Nicholas Krasnov said, you can test it in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4).

But if you ever find yourself about to use where rownum = 1 in a subquery, alarm bells should go off, because in 90% of the cases you are doing something wrong. Very rarely will you need a random value. Only when all selected values are the same, a rownum = 1 is valid.

In this case I expect calendar_id to be a primary key in calendar. Therefor each record in hrs can only have 1 plan_week_id selected per record. So the where rownum = 1 is not required.

And to answer your question: Yes, it will run just fine. Though the brackets around each where clause are also not required and in fact only confusing (me).

Comment: Ah, I thought 'first 1', 'top 1', or 'rownum=1' was required **beforehand** (together with selecting only one field) to let the SQL engine know that only one value will be returned, i.e. that the SQL is valid (with set fieldname=). Is that assumption incorrect, i.e. is this only checked when the subquery returns its results (FireBird, Oracle, SQL Server)? I know that only one record will be returned but the SQL engine doesn't ;-)

Comment: As far as Oracle is concerned, in this case it trusts you. Well, actually.. I bet it doesn't trust you, but it will try to execute the query anyway.